# is this inequality valid for any $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability

> Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two continuous random variables with marginal
>   density $f(x)$ and $g(y)$. Is it true that
>
> $$ E( \ln f(X) ) \geq E( \ln g(X)) $$

this would be true iff $ln f(X) \geq \ln g(X)$ which is turn would be true as long as

$$ f(X) \geq g(X) $$

but then we have nothing special about f and g, just that they are densities. I feel this result may be false, but I cant find a counterexample. Any ideas?

Comment: I mean, if you just switch the names f,g you have inequality in the other direction, so your only concern is then equality for all f,g.

Comment: As mentioned, since the statement is symmetric, you are actually asking if $$\mathbb{E}[\ln f(X)] = \mathbb{E}[\ln g(Y)]$$ for every two continuous r.v.'s $X,Y$ with densities$f,g$ respectively. It's simple to check with counterexamples: $X$ uniform on $[0,1]$ gives $\mathbb{E}[\ln f(X)] = 0$, $Y$ uniform on $[0,2]$ gives $\mathbb{E}[\ln g(Y)] = -\ln 2$. (Note that for these two, $f,g$ are constant.)